# Problemas com soma de valores com C# e MYSql

Tags: c#, mysql

Eu estou desenvolvendo um software que cataloga mangás, um dos problemas que eu estou tendo é com a entrada de volumes.
O que deveria acontecer: o usuário definiu o numVolumes para 2, ou seja, ele vai adicionar mais 2 volumes de mangás para tabela mangá.
Porém esse código não está funcionando.
numVolues é NumericUpDown e o txtIdtambém.

```
private void btndicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            strMysql = "update manga set volumes = volumes + " + Convert.ToInt(numVolumes.Value) + " where idManga " + txtId.Value + ";";

            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(strMysql, con);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                //eu comentei esses códigos por não achar necessário
                //comando.Parameters.Clear();
                //comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soma", numVolumes.Value);


                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro:\n" + erro);


            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();

            }
```

Comment: Melhor assim, porque este código sofre de SQL Injection, então não funcionar é bem mais interessante, conserte isso primeiro e você sabe como fazer porque está nos comentários, depois pense na solução para esse problema da soma (eu sei que alguém vai responder isso sem se preocupar com a segurança porque é fácil não ter responsabilidade sobre o erro. Ainda tem erros de conversão que vai quebrar a aplicação e captura de exceção errada. Pesquise aqui no site que tem como fazer do jeito correto.

Comment: A linha que começa com `strMysql = "update...` tem um erro, se é uma string, o `Convert.ToInt(numVolumes.Value)` vai dar erro ao concatenar, se deixar só o `numVolumes.Value` deve funcionar

Comment: Mas como já foi comentado, fazer para evitar o SQL Injection seria interessante montar uma query parametrizada, tem exemplos aqui no site. Se não encontrar bem o que precisa, comente aqui para ajudarmos

Comment: está faltando o sinal de igual  ->  " where idManga = "  , se for tipo texto coloque o sinal de igual e aspas simples concatenando com paramentro e finalizando com aspas simples.